# WIFi option not found in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 today. But when I installed it I didn't find any wifi options. After the installation I searched the settings for wifi but I didn't find any. What can I do now?

I have run some commands but I didn't have any USB cable to show the outputs, so I took some pictures but the quality is very bad.
[image: nothing]
[image]

Comment: Are you using a USB wireless device or a built-in PCI device?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get your question. I am using a laptop basically. Asus

Comment: Then post the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

Comment: It shows no output

Comment: Then post output of `lspci`

Comment: There are 17 lines of output. How can I write it? can I send u a picture ?

Comment: You can save text from the terminal to a file. Then post it to your question.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the output via picture . I told u I don't have anything that  I can use to move files from my laptop to my mobile .

Comment: There is no PCI device. Maybe it is an SDIO device. Post output of `dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: it shows no output

Comment: Then it is a hardware problem. There is no wireless device detected.

Comment: Okay, I am going to check it out then.

Comment: `sudo journalctl  -b 0` will page through log entries beginning at the current boot. You can watch as your system discovers your hardware, initializes (or fails to initialize) it, starts system services, ... including your WiFi interface. You may have to download a driver. How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: by a pendrive. I think that too. but which driver that I don't know and how. and that command shows unlimited output and I am not understanding anything